# Trouble with Beziers in Inkscape after switching from Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, inkscape, drawing, path

So this is my first post as I just very recently downloaded and tried Inkscape after roughly 7 years of Illustrator. As far as I can say this program is really amazing, although I am struggling with some basics.

1. If I draw a path with the Bezier tool and don't like the last Node, can I delete it somehow without losing the entire path?
2. If I miss-click and '**finish**' a path, is it possible to continue working with the Bezier tool on an open Node? If yes — How? If no — Why?!
3. Is it possible to break a Node to have only one handle while drawing? For example: I have a smooth curve but then I want an abrupt edge to then draw along? How the explanation makes sense.. ?
4. Is it possible to move the active node while you draw?

As you can see there are some features from Illustrator I am massively accustomed to. I hope somebody can help me out, because I feel like a small child again.

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 2):

You can edit nodes using the `Node Tool` (<kbd>F2</kbd> by default). Deleting the last point of an open path works as it does in Illustrator. Closed paths need to be split at a node in order to become open - deleting a node is like removing an anchor point. The `Node Tool's` toolbar has all of these commands by default.

[image]

To create a corner point while drawing with the `Pen Tool`, hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd>. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is the angle constraint modifier. After a path is created, you can alter a node's style with the `Node Tool` Toolbar, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Clicking on a node to cycle through the options.

I don't think that you can edit or move nodes before finalizing their path. For that matter, `Undo` doesn't work mid-path-creation either.

Answer (score 2):

When drawing a path, you can undo your last node using <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

2. only for open paths: you can select the path, then switch to the bezier-tool. You get two squares on the path's ends, click on one of them and continue drawing. (Works also for the pencil).

4. I don't think this is possible